# Mysql get products count for each product parameter value (Many-To-Many relation)

Tags: mysql, count, relation

I'm trying to get number of products for each parameter value and also take into account currently selected parameters values, but I have really no idea, how to make it.
I'm thinking about method, where I will make subquery to get this count, but I'm not sure about it and about its performance. Do you have any idea how to make it?
E.g.
I have this parameters and values:

Color: red, blue, green
Size: S,M,L,XL
Material: Cotton, Silk

And now, I select e.g. Red color and size S. Now I want to get number of products for each parameter value and which has Color: red (parameter value nmb 1) and Size: S (parameter value nmb 5).

I have this table structure:

**product**:
*product_ID*
Data:

```
product_ID
1
2
3
```

**product_product_param_value**:
*product_product_param_value_ID, product_ID,product_param_value_ID*
Data:

```
product_ID     product_param_value_ID
1              1
1              5
1              10
```

**product_param_value**:
*product_param_value_ID,title,
product_param_ID*
Data:

```
product_param_value_ID   title      product_param_ID
1                        Red        10
5                        S          11
10                       Cotton     12
```

**product_param**:
*product_param_ID, title*

```
product_param_ID      title
10                    Color
11                    Size
12                    Material
```

In this data example, when I select Color: Red and Size: S => At parameter Material value Cotton it should return 1, because there is just one product, which has Color: Red, Size: S and Material: Cotton.

In my opinion, it would be something like this:
- in this situation, I select from first parameter value 1 and for second parameter value 5

```
SELECT product_parameter_value.*, 
       (
       SELECT count(product_product_parameter_value.product_ID)
       FROM product_product_parameter_value
       WHERE product_product_parameter_value.product_parameter_value_ID = 1 AND product_product_parameter_value.product_parameter_value_ID = 5
       ) as productsCount,

FROM product_parameter_value
```

I will try to sum up my question:
I need to find out way, how to get **product_ID** from **product_product_param_value**, which has e.g. 2 **product_param_value_IDs** stored in table **product_product_param_value**

Comment: Please tell us what you've already tried. Moreover you used _orm_ as tag for this question, but no framwork name. Are you sure ?

Comment: I used Laravel5. Anyway, I want to make custom query. I will remove the tag.

Comment: In your query you have a conflict: the value cannot be 1 and 5 at the same time. You need to have two separate declarations for parameters (with aliases) and link them to the product

Comment: It is possible. I will edit my question, to show you, how I mean it.